# Input border immediately disappear after submit click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

stackoverflow.

So, I created a simple form like a boss.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name = "username">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And added a little script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("input:submit").click(function(){
           $("input[name=username]").css("border", "1px solid red");
       })
    });
```

What I want? I want after click the input box highlight. But want I have right now? I press the send button, of course input field highlight, but this highlight immediately disappear and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: submiting the FORM reloads the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using submit button.That button doing the reload as it default event.use `event.PreventDefault();`.It will stop the page being reloaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("input:submit").click(function(event){
             event.PreventDefault();
           $("input[name=username]").css("border", "1px solid red");
       })
    });
```

Otherwise you can change your button type from submit to button

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name = "username">
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
```

Comment: @KarelGi have mentioned it before you comment.any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

click a submit button will reoload the page you can solve this by changing your button type to `button` from `submit`

```
  <input type="button" value="Submit">
```